# Adding own cssfile to angularJS doesn't compile with grunt serve:dist

Tags: javascript, html, css, angularjs

I am making my own angular project,

I made for the main page my own css file

> main-page.css

I added this css file to my head:

```
<head>
//...
<link rel="stylesheet" href="styles/main-page.css">
//...
</head>
```

I also added a link to my routeProvider

```
//...
.when('/', {
        templateUrl: 'views/main.html',
        controller: 'MainCtrl',
        css: 'styles/main-page.css'
      })
//...
```

The grunt tasks

```
    grunt.registerTask('serve', 'Compile then start a connect web server', function (target) {
    if (target === 'dist') {
      return grunt.task.run(['build', 'connect:dist:keepalive']);
    }

    grunt.task.run([
      'clean:server',
      'wiredep',
      'concurrent:server',
      'autoprefixer:server',
      'connect:livereload',
      'watch'
    ]);
  });

  grunt.registerTask('server', 'DEPRECATED TASK. Use the "serve" task instead', function (target) {
    grunt.log.warn('The `server` task has been deprecated. Use `grunt serve` to start a server.');
    grunt.task.run(['serve:' + target]);
  });

  grunt.registerTask('test', [
    'clean:server',
    'wiredep',
    'concurrent:test',
    'autoprefixer',
    'connect:test',
    'karma'
  ]);

  grunt.registerTask('build', [
    'clean:dist',
    'wiredep',
    'useminPrepare',
    'concurrent:dist',
    'autoprefixer',
    'concat',
    'ngAnnotate',
    'copy:dist',
    'cdnify',
    'cssmin',
    'uglify',
    'filerev',
    'usemin',
    'htmlmin'
  ]);

  grunt.registerTask('default', [
    'newer:jshint',
    'test',
    'build'
  ]);
```

When I do grunt serve, my css is properly loaded into my main page, if I do grunt serve:dist it doesn't. Than my css file is ignored.

I added the css code of my own file to the auto generated main.scss file from AngularJS. But this isn't a proper solution.

Did I forget something or did I do something wrong?

Comment: What is your Gruntflies.js content for these two cases?

Comment: which part do you want to see?

Comment: Typically a grunt task called serve:dist first compiles the app using a build step.  Maybe you could show the 'grunt.registerTask('build' step listed in the gruntfile.js.

Comment: The build step in the Yeoman generated gruntfile will deposit your css file in the dist/styles directory within your project.  I'm assuming that's what you're using.  Do you see your main-page.css file in that location, possibly with a alphanumeric prefix?

Comment: 2 files are there, main.a4eaa488.css and vendor.d41d8cd9.css

Comment: So I need to delete this reference?

Comment: No, don't delete the reference.  Check your index.html for the build:css.  Here, I've included your extra main-extra file reference between build:css and endbuild.  After you run the grunt build, look for the css contents from main-extra.css at the end of the main.css file.  I just tried this and it seemed to work: <!-- build:css({.tmp,app}) styles/main.css -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles/main.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles/main-extra.css">
  <!-- endbuild -->